# Would a question asking about how Steam's 'recommendations' feature works on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

**TL;DR:** Is it on-topic to ask questions like "if I do X action on Steam, does it change/affect Steam recommendations?"

I'm not very familiar with or active on this community. Is this an appropriate place to ask about actions that affect Steam recommendations?

I found some questions about Steam itself (eg. why game X crashes on Steam, what is Steam, etc.) but this is slightly different. I have two questions about how I can feed data into Steam recommendations to get better recommendations out.

Also, aside from whether this is on-topic, it's likely nobody will know the answer (outside of Steam developers). So, is it also practical to ask these  types of questions here?

Comment: (Sidenote before someone potentially accidentally answers this incorrectly: this is NOT talking about recommendation requests, it's talking about the game recommendations feature of Steam.)

Comment: Yes, it's on-topic.  See [Why are Steam questions on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/why-are-steam-questions-on-topic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in general Steam questions are on-topic, as long as they're actually about Steam *(and not generic tech questions disguised as Steam questions)*.

The reasoning is that this is a community of gaming-experts, and those are questions a gaming-expert would be uniquely qualified to answer.  They're also questions that might be generally useful to other gamers.

See [Why are Steam questions on-topic?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/why-are-steam-questions-on-topic) for more details